# Wireless card unseen by lspci

Tags: wireless, drivers

I installed both Ubuntu 8.04 and 10.04. I tried to install the wireless card. although I succeeded in installing the driver using ndiswrapper, it tells me that the hardware is not present.

When I use lspci, it doesn't list it. I have this laptop model and I think it should have the same entry about the wireless card here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1810193

Could the problem be other than hardware malfunction?

Update:
Here's lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RS480 Host Bridge (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RS480 PCI Bridge
00:13.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 USB Host Controller
00:13.1 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 USB Host Controller
00:13.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 USB2 Host Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 SMBus Controller (rev 11)
00:14.1 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 IDE Controller
00:14.3 ISA bridge: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 PCI-ISA Bridge
00:14.4 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 PCI-PCI Bridge
00:14.5 Multimedia audio controller: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:14.6 Modem: ATI Technologies Inc SB400 AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 02)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Radeon XPRESS 200M 5955 (PCIE)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
05:09.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCIxx21/x515 Cardbus Controller
05:09.2 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller
05:09.3 Mass storage controller: Texas Instruments PCIxx21 Integrated FlashMedia Controller
05:09.4 SD Host controller: Texas Instruments PCI6411/6421/6611/6621/7411/7421/7611/7621 Secure Digital Controller
```

Unfortunately I'm using Ubuntu 8.04 since it is the last LTS that runs with acceptable performance.

Comment: Post the output of lspci here. try updating your system with wired lan and then see if you find the hardware in the list.

Comment: I've updated the question with the output of lspci

Comment: try with ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issue where :`lspci` doesn't list any wireless device/card
`ifconfig` won't list any wireless interface
`rfkill` won't make any change 
not able to turn on wireless
network manager won't list any wireless
`dmesg` won't say anything related to wireless

one thing you can see that you may have usb wireless instead of pci it is possible for 
internal wireless too.so see the output of 
`lsusb` and look for your wireless card. Well i wasn't able to find why this occurs i tried everything like reinstalling drivers,
recompiling drivers etc but could not find a fix this way .I think there is something close
to hardware (at least in my case)that's why you can not fix it using software/drivers.

**I found a quick fix:**
Goto BIOS settings you will probably find wireless enabled there if this is so disable it reboot again go to BIOS settings again now enable it your wireless should work now

this worked for me, try it well .I have been struggling with this and could not find a
conclusion. If anyone finds it please reply.

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 18.04 also. I have a Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 here. This solved to me.

Comment: Worked for me two on Fedora 30 - after the an update lspci did not list the Wireless Adapter anymore. Your quickfix solved the issue and wifi is working again.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same issue. I was looking for solution for this but unfortunately there are many people facing this issue but no straight answer to my problem so I will just tell you what worked for me and you can try the same. It may work for you as well.

1. go to software updater
2. update your Ubuntu version
3. It should ask you to reboot the machine, so do it.
4. when you are back run following commands in terminal.
5. `sudo apt-get update`
6. `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`
7. disconnect the wired connection
8. turn on wifi (FN+f2)